# How do I edit parts of my csv file at a time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a function that changes values of my csv file with edits in it and with a method, but i think that the since the main function used df = pd.read_csv() before the method, it's to_csv would only set the file to the original with the changes made minus the methods changes to it since df wouldn't include the changes from the method.

```py
df = pd.csv('/Users/Bramblestar/FBot/factions.csv', index_col=0)
setFacVal(gId, cId, 2, value)
df[str(gId)][row] = value2
df.to_csv('/Users/Bramblestar/FBot/factions.csv')
```

```py
def setFacVal(gId, cId, fType, fValue):
    #0name 1points 2description 3color 4role 5opRole
    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Bramblestar/FBot/factions.csv', index_col=0)
    df.iloc[fType, list(df.keys()).index(str(gId))] = fValue
    df.to_csv('/Users/Bramblestar/FBot/factions.csv')
```

Is there a pd.read_csv parameter that gives me only the part that i want to edit? or a way to use to_csv in a way that it only replaces part of the file with the edited one from the copy?

Comment: Standard filesystem semantics mean you can only rewrite parts of a file in place if the new content has the exact same length in bytes as the content it's replacing. That's almost never true for a CSV, so CSV format in general isn't amenable to being edited in place without rewriting the whole file (or at least, everything past the point where you made the edit).

Comment: ... The above is part of why databases have their own heavily optimized file formats. The _easy_ way to get that yourself is to use a prebuilt database format, like sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is to pass your dataframe to `setFacVal`.  It's not very efficient to read and write the file multiple times.

```
def setFacVal(df, gId, cId, fType, fValue):
    #0name 1points 2description 3color 4role 5opRole
    df.iloc[fType, list(df.keys()).index(str(gId))] = fValue
```